# How to crop Google GeoChart and center its content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

My goal is to show smaller part of [Google Geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart). 
As I know, I can not simply zoom in and move. So I was trying to crop and change position of cropped area of Geochart which I would like to show ([image example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0loOm.png)). I saw some examples how to do it using CSS and `<div>` which were for text or background image but it does not work for me.

Map is placed on the page by `<div id='visualization'>`

Any solutions how to crop and set cropped area of Google GeoChart?

Comment: paste some code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution for the issue: 
`<div style="position: absolute; top: -360px; left: -380px; width: 200%; clip: rect(360px, 950px, 686px, 300px);" id='visualization'></div>`

I move the content by: `position: absolute; top: -360px; left: -380px;`

and cropped the area by: `clip: rect(360px, 950px, 686px, 300px);`

Comment: I, too, needed to enlarge a region for my usage.  I have provided a slightly different approach with some extra flourishes and explanations at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961972/change-center-of-google-map-geochart/41613463#41613463